# Требует правки или копия?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, дубликаты

В основном списке вопросов [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568289/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-enum-%D0%B8-enum-class) помечен как `[требует правки]`:

[image: требует правки]

однако на самом деле это `[копия]`. В чем можно убедиться зайдя на страницу вопроса:

[image: копия]

Пока писал вопрос вместо `[требует правки]` стало `[копия]`. 
Это какой-то лаг с кэшированием или в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на кэш. Проверил, вопрос сразу был закрыт как дубликат.

Сейчас корректно показывается: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но почему такой странный кэш? Т.е. откуда вообще взялось `[требует правки]`?